# How to SVN commit all files with the same prefix

Tags: linux, svn, commit, prefix, opensuse

I have files with `noviembre` as a prefix and I want to commit all of them at once.

I tried this command: `svn commit noviembre*.doc --message "deleted".`

I can do them 1 by 1 or add all the files names in 1 command but there are a lot of files.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I am using Opensuse 31.1.

Answer (score 1):

The log message "deleted" suggests that you have deleted these files.

That is the reason why the wildcard does not work: The wildcard expansion ("globbing") is done by the shell, and it expands to any existing files that the shell can find and that match your pattern. Well, you *deleted* them so this returns nothing.

Committing the folder that contains all those `noviembre` files will work, but hopefully you have not done any modifications in other files that you do not want committed. Otherwise you'll have a bit of work ahead, moving files out of your working copy and later moving them back.

**EDIT:** Or, as suggested by rene, do a parse of `svn status`. That's actually a genious idea.

Comment: @rene: Unluckily, I stink at writing regex, hehehe... would probably take me 5 times longer to that simple regex right than it would take me to do the matching by hand in a text editor (which btw. would be a valid approach for me if it's fewer than 50 files). But for someone who is moderately good at regex, this should be 10 seconds :)